# Device Independent Pixel Scaling In Browser

Tags: css, density-independent-pixel

I was following a video tutorial and it stated that the browser in a chromebook has a viewport width of 1280 DIPS and in this case they stated that the 1280 DIPS will be scaled up to the 2560 hardware pixels of the chromebook when the page is rendered on a display.

I understand the DPR is 2 in this case, so 1 DIP will take up 2 hardware pixels. But does this DPI number of 1280 represent the logical resolution and does it refer to the CSS pixel? I am confused on why the viewport only takes up 1280px and not the entire 2560px. Like what is the purpose of DIPS?

Comment: While the screen has 2560 pixels in it's width, it report's half that size to the browser.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides But why does it report half that size to the browser? Why is it using DIP instead of the hardware pixel?

Comment: DPI would vary considerably across devices - Imagine responsive design(having to create media queries) based on the DPI of each and every device. I'm not adding this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure this is the *only* reason this is the case - I'm pretty sure it's one of the *main* reasons though.

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah I figured it would be responsive design.